# Export-SPWeb: Unable to export some lists

Tags: list, powershell, script

I'm using the following script to export some lists:

```
foreach($spListUrl in $deploymentXml.Configuration.Lists.ListUrl)
{
    Export-SPWeb -Identity $pwaSiteUrl -ItemUrl $spListUrl -Path $listExportFilePath -IncludeUserSecurity -IncludeVersions 4 -NoFileCompression -Force
}
```

I previously got the URLs using:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $webAppUrl
foreach ($list in $web.lists)
{
     $list.RootFolder.Url
}
```

The thing is that the script does export some lists while when trying to export other I get this error:

```
Export-SPWeb : The URL provided is invalid. Only valid URLs that are site collections or sites are allowed to be exported using stsadm.exe.
```

I've checked all the URLs and all of them exist so I don't know where the problem could be.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but in case you are still looking for an answer: the value of the ItemURL parameter has to be a valid relative URL, i.e. it has to start with a / character. Check the values you are putting in $spListUrl.